# Insertion sorting

Tags: java, arrays, oop, sorting, object

I'm trying to sort an array by title, studio, year.

```
movies[0] = new Movie2("The Muppets Take Manhattan","Columbia Tristar", 2001);
```

I'm having trouble on how to create the constructor for the sorting method. I don't have a idea on how to separate all three elements to sort them all individually.

Comment: So, what have your online searches for "sort array java" yielded?

Comment: I'm sorry, you wouldn't build a constructor for a sort method, you build a constructor for class objects.

Comment: @Welshboy I know that, I used the word constructor like this  public static void sortYear(Movie2[] movies, int n)

Comment: @Galaga In Java, that is referred to as a `method`

Comment: Let me know what you think about my solution, if you even bother to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is better learned by practice instead of providing the answer. Check out the section from The Java Tutorials on [Object Ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)

Hint: You will want to implement the `Comparable` interface.

Answer (score 4):

You may have got it working already, but I came up with an answer, so I'll post it anyways. I haven't implemented the `Comparator` `interface` into the `Movie` class; instead, I just use [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5b%5d,%20java.util.Comparator%29) and a custom `Comparator` to sort it by some property of the movie.

Here is the [`Movie` class](http://code.mikeyaworski.com/sample_code/movie) I created, just for reference. Here is the code I used to sort an example:

```
Movie a = new Movie("The Muppets Take Manhattan", "Columbia Tristar", 2001);
Movie b = new Movie("Fight Club", "Regency Enterprises", 1999);
Movie c = new Movie("Toy Story", "Walt Disney Pictures", 1995);

Movie[] movies = {a, b, c};

// compares the TITLES in ASCENDING order
Arrays.sort(movies, new Comparator<Movie>() {
    public int compare(Movie m1, Movie m2) {
        return m1.getTitle().compareTo(m2.getTitle());
    }
});

// print out the sorted movie array
for (Movie m : movies) {
    System.out.println(m + "\n---");
}
```

If you wanted to put the order to be descending, you could simply reverse the order you are comparing the values in the Comparator. For example, you would change this:

```
return m1.getTitle().compareTo(m2.getTitle());
```

to this:

```
return m2.getTitle().compareTo(m1.getTitle());
```

If you wanted to compare different properties of the `Movie`, just change `getTitle()` to something else, like `getYear()` or `getStudio()`. Example:

```
return m1.getYear() - m2.getYear(); // ascending by year
```

Because the year is in an `int`, you cannot use the String `compareTo` method, you just have to return the difference.

---

To make this order the movies depending on input, look at [this code](http://code.mikeyaworski.com/sample_code/movie_ordering). I didn't want to daunt you right away.